# Isolate function from executing from several threads using sync objects

Tags: java, multithreading

Trying to isolate function `actionPerformed()` from executing from several threads using synchronization object. Unfortunately this not helps and function is executed even if another function has entered `synchronized (reqSync)`. Why? How to solve this problem?

```
public class MnemonicEx1 extends JFrame
{

    public JeasiHandler jh = null;
    private Log log = Log.getLog();
    public static Object reqSync = new Object();

    public MnemonicEx1()
    {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI()
    {

        JButton btnAuth = new JButton("1");
        btnAuth.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_B);

        createLayout(btnAuth);

        setTitle("****");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        btnAuth.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {

            // @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                synchronized (reqSync)
                {
                    new Thread()
                    {

                        public void run()
                        {
                            System.out.println("starting");
                            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    Thread.sleep(100);
                                    System.out.println(Integer.toString(i));
                                } catch (InterruptedException ex)
                                {
                                    ex.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                            System.out.println("finishing");
                        }

                    }.start();

                }
            }

        });

    }

    private void createLayout(JComponent authButn)
    {

        Container pane = getContentPane();
        GroupLayout gl = new GroupLayout(pane);
        pane.setLayout(gl);

        gl.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

        int i = 0;
        gl.setHorizontalGroup(
                gl.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(authButn)
        );

        gl.setVerticalGroup(gl.createParallelGroup()
                .addComponent(authButn)
        );

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {

            public void run()
            {
                MnemonicEx1 ex = new MnemonicEx1();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {

            public void run()
            {
                MnemonicEx1 ex = new MnemonicEx1();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of your current attempt, the synchronization needs to be inside the thread. All you are currently preventing is the starting of multiple threads at the same time; you aren't stopping them running simultaneously once started.

```
new Thread() {
  public void run() {
    synchronized (reqSync) {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Note that you might actually want to do something a *little* different from this - this doesn't prevent the user pressing the button lots of times, and queueing up lots of threads which will then run one at a time.

Instead, you can make it so that subsequent clicks to the block are discarded until the thread completes:

```
// As a member variable instead of reqSync:
static final Semaphore MUTEX = new Semaphore(1);

// In the body:
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  if (MUTEX.tryAcquire()) {
    new Thread() {
      @Override public void run() {
        try {
          // ...
        } finally {
          MUTEX.release();
        }
      }
    }.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I must use java 1.4 and there is no Semaphore

Comment: Java 1.4? I didn't realize it was still 2002.

Answer (score 0):

Given then you want to use a global synchronization, using threads here doesn't make sense. I'd recommend simplifying this code to be:

```
// @Override
```

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

```
  synchronized (reqSync) {
     System.out.println("starting");
     for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        try {
           Thread.sleep(100);
           System.out.println(Integer.toString(i));
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
     System.out.println("finishing");
  }
```

}